# creating map with dash getting syntax errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, plotly-dash

I am new to Dash and python, i am simply practicing an example which contains map graph, while executing the program i am getting syntax errors. can any one help me on this? ref: https://codepen.io/Dorkaitz/pen/QmooBK
the below one is my code :

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import pandas as pd

Plotly.d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_february_us_airport_traffic.csv',

 function(err, rows){
      function unpack(rows, key) {
          return rows.map(function(row) { return row[key]; });
      }

var scl = [[0,'rgb(5, 10, 172)'],[0.35,'rgb(40, 60, 190)'],[0.5,'rgb(70, 100, 245)'], [0.6,'rgb(90, 120, 245)'],[0.7,'rgb(106, 137, 247)'],[1,'rgb(220, 220, 220)']];  

var data = [{
    type:'scattergeo',
    locationmode: 'USA-states',
    lon: unpack(rows, 'long'),
    lat: unpack(rows, 'lat'),
    hoverinfor:  unpack(rows, 'airport'),
    text:  unpack(rows, 'airport'),
    mode: 'markers',
    marker: {
      size: 8,
      opacity: 0.8,
      reversescale: true,
      autocolorscale: false,
      symbol: 'round',
      line: {
        width: 1,
        color: 'rgb(102,102,102)'
      },
      colorscale: scl,
      cmin: 0,
      color: unpack(rows, 'cnt'),
    }
}];


var layout = {
      colorbar: false,
      autoscale: 1,
      showgrid: 1,
      margin: {t: 0, l: 0, r: 0, b: 0},
      geo: {
        autoscale: 1,
        scope: "world",
        projection: {
          type: 'mercator',
        },
        lonaxis: { range: [-169, 191] },
        lataxis: { range: [-3, 90] },
        showframe: false,
        showlegend: false,
        showland: true,
        showocean: true,
        showscale: true,
        landcolor: 'rgb(62,71,80)',
        oceancolor: 'rgb(33,43,54)',
        subunitcolor: 'rgb(217,217,217)',
        countrycolor: 'rgb(217,217,217)',
        countrywidth: 0.5,
        subunitwidth: 0.5,
        fixedrange: true,
        scrollzoom: false
      }
    };

Plotly.plot(myDiv, data, layout, {scrollZoom: false});

  var geo = Plotly.plot;
  console.log(geo);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This code isnt python, var? ";"? not properly intended. Clearly you need more work before asking at SO